# How to convert json data in json file in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, json, laravel

I need convert my json data in file `.json`. I parsing data to `array of json` in this code

```
$movies = Movie::all();
return response()->json($movies);
```

I need create `movies.json` file. Where my file must be, which folder? And how to  it?

Comment: Do you want to offer it as download, or just want to create it on the server?

Comment: For now, I want create it on the server.

Comment: put it in public directory and access it via domain.com/movies.json

Comment: @AleksandarMihailovic , please check my answer

Comment: @Koen when somebody go to my route /movies.json i must make file and send file to user..It is all

Comment: @AleksandarMihailovic I'm able to help you with the asked question, but when you ask me to explain the basics of Laravel, I advise you to read the documentation and watch some example. I can't explain the the basis of coding/the basics of Laravel.

Comment: @mistry Okey how i can create movies.json file and sent their movies.json to user when user come to route /moives.json

Answer (score 11):

use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

and then

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('movies.json', response()->json($movies));
```

and this file will be save in public folder

Comment: Did I need create file in public folder like movies.json?

Comment: Keep in mind that saving sensitive data in public folder can be dangerous!

Answer (score 2):

According to the fact that you want to create the file on the server, maybe you can use the file-storage functions in Laravel like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$movies = Movie::all();
Storage::put('Movies.json', $movies);
return true;
```

In the future, if you want to offer it as a download you can create a response macro. I've done the same for a HTML download

File: App\Providers\AppServiceProvider@boot

```
\Response::macro('attachment', function ($content) {

            $headers = [
                'Content-type' => 'text/json',
                'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename='Movies.json'",
            ];

            return \Response::make($content, 200, $headers);

        });
```

And call it as

```
return response()->attachment($movies); //App\Providers\AppServiceProvider
```

Comment: I am beginner in Laravel. I don't know where I can create json file? In MoviesController or another file?

Comment: @AleksandarMihailovic You've shared an example in your post. Can you place it in that file?

Comment: @KoenHollander what if you have 50000 rows ?

Answer (score 1):

in your `web.php`

```
Route::get('/download','MoviesController@downloadJSON')->name('download_movies');
```

paste below code in your controller :

```
 public function downloadJSON(Request $request){
         $table = Movie::all();
         $filename = "movies.json";
         $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
         fputs($handle, $table->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
         fclose($handle);
         $headers = array('Content-type'=> 'application/json');
         return response()->download($filename,'movies.json',$headers);
    }
```

read more about [Response download](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-downloads)